# How to write query in influxDb groups by time and returns two new fields using agregation?

Tags: sql, influxdb, influxdb-2

Im storing the following data in fluxDb

`influxRepository.storeEvent(new Point("MyMeasurement").addField("p", data.someNumber()).time(now(),WritePrecision.S));`

I want to query the data grouped by minute and get the smallest and largest number for every minute, starting in the last 30 minutes.

Example Input:
Measurement        field  p   time
MyMeasurement             1      1
MyMeasurement             4      1
MyMeasurement             3      2

....

What I want to get is from the query is

Measurement       minP  maxP  time
MyMeasurement      1     4     1
MyMeasurement      3     3     1

So I'm storing only one value in the db, but I want to query the group by time and aggregate to find the smallest and the biggest p for every minute.

I need something like this:
`select max(p), min(p) from MyMeasurement group by time`